# Qt(C++) Unexpected result about two different way to dynamic allocate QProgressbar

Tags: c++, qt

I was creating a game, which including character have their own health bar(Qprogressbar)

I provide some sample code which is doing similar thing in my project.

Following code is trying to use `connect` to generate new QProgressbar each second, but it can't generate any progressbar in using `connect`.

The part I think most strange is when I use `my->add_bar();`(in my mainwindow.cpp) can generate progress bar.(repeat it can also generate multiple bar)

My question is why `my->add_bar()` and `connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),my,SLOT(add_bar()))` will cause different result? And how can I do to make my `connect` reach my expect(generate bar each second)?

Following is my sample code, and thanks for your reading

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProgressBar>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

jet *my = new jet(this);
QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
timer->start(1000);
//following two line cause different result
my->add_bar();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),my,SLOT(add_bar()));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;}
```

jet.cpp

```
#include "jet.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow* jet::tmp_window;
jet::jet(){
 };
jet::jet(MainWindow *window)
{
tmp_window = window;//access MainWindow*, because QProgresbar's constructor need it
}
void jet::add_bar()
{
 QProgressBar *a = new QProgressBar(tmp_window) ;
 a->setRange(0,10);
 a->setGeometry(qrand()%100,qrand()%100,70,20);//display in different position
 a->setValue(5);
}
```

jet.h

```
#ifndef JET_H
#define JET_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QProgressBar>

class MainWindow;//if not add this,project dont know who is mainwindow
class jet: public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
 public:
  jet();
  jet(MainWindow *window);
 public slots:
  void add_bar();
 private:
   static MainWindow *tmp_window;
  };

  #endif // JET_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include "jet.h"
namespace Ui {
   class MainWindow;
 }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
 explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
jet *my_jet;
private:
 Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: add `a->show();`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work!